# EXT Scheduler - cannot create view preset

Tags: javascript, extjs, scheduler

I am attempting to change the calendar header date layout in EXT Scheduler. I've copied the section of code from the customer header demo, made a few changes, and dropped it into my code.

The problem is I get "**Sch.preset is undefined**", where I'm executing "**Sch.preset.Manager.registerPreset("weekView", weekView);**". I'm not sure of this is a scoping issue or whether I'm missing some code completely.

```
Ext.onReady(function () {


    var weekView = {
        displayDateFormat : 'Y-m-d',
        shiftIncrement : 1,
        shiftUnit : "WEEK",
        timeResolution : {
            unit : "DAY",
            increment : 1
        },
        headerConfig : {
            bottom : {
                unit : "DAY",
                dateFormat : 'D d M'
            },
            middle: {
                unit : "QUARTER",
                renderer : function(start, end, cfg) {
                    var quarter = Math.floor(start.getMonth() / 3) + 1,
                        fiscalQuarter = quarter === 4 ? 1 : (quarter + 1);

                    return "" //Ext.String.format('FQ{0} {1}', fiscalQuarter, start.getFullYear() + (fiscalQuarter === 1 ? 1 : 0));
                }
            },
            top : {
                unit : "YEAR",
                cellGenerator : function(viewStart, viewEnd) {
                    var cells = [];

                    // Simplified scenario, assuming view will always just show one US fiscal year
                    return [{
                        start : viewStart,
                        end : viewEnd,
                        header : 'Fiscal Year ' + (viewStart.getMonth() + 1)
                    }];
                }
            }
        }
    };

    Sch.preset.Manager.registerPreset("weekView", weekView);


    Sked.init();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 Sch.PresetManager.registerPreset("weekView", weekView);
```